# Deleting rows with removed comments from dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I am trying to do some data cleaning. I have removed the rows with "nan" using pandas dropna, but I still don't know how to drop all the rows with "[removed]" (This picture shows the head of my dataset). Any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you in advance :)

[image: picture]

Comment: `df[df.Body.ne('[removed]')]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean-indexing:

```py
mask = df.Body.eq("[removed]")
df = df[~mask]
print(df)
```